# Protobuf-net Causing Certification Failure on Windows Phone Store

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, windows-phone-store

I recently started using the protobuf-net library as a way to get around the lack of binary serialization in .Net Core on Windows Phone 8.1 for a port of an existing game.

So far protobuf-net has been working great for me. However when I came to submit the app it is failing the certification tests. The report lists various methods and classes belonging in the protobuf-net dll as being unsupported APIs.

An example from this report is:

This API is not supported for this application type - Api=System.Reflection.Emit.Label. Module=MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=7CEC85D7BEA7798E. File=protobuf-net.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod. Module=MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=7CEC85D7BEA7798E. File=protobuf-net.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator. Module=MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=7CEC85D7BEA7798E. File=protobuf-net.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=System.Reflection.Emit.LocalBuilder. Module=MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=7CEC85D7BEA7798E. File=protobuf-net.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=System.Reflection.MemberTypes. Module=MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=7CEC85D7BEA7798E. File=protobuf-net.dll.

There are many more but I have left them out for brevity. However as far as I can tell the MSDN documentation states that each of these APIs **ARE** supported on Windows Phone 8.1. Certainly in my own tests the library has been working correctly on device for some weeks when deploying from Visual Studio.

Is anyone aware of any steps that I could be missing here, some flag that needs setting in the package manifest or something like that? Or could I be using an incorrect version of protobuf-net (I built the dll from the WindowsPhone8.0 project)?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Is your app a Universal app, or a Silverlight app?

Comment: It's a Universal app

Answer (score 0):

As you're doing this as a Universal app, you're restricting yourself to the APIs that will also be available to desktop apps, and whilst part of the [`System.Reflection.Emit` namespace is there, it does not include those classes that your error message refers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441595.aspx).

Comment: Ok so based on that I've now modified the project to a Windows Phone 8.1 project instead of Universal.
The WACK test is failing wit the same errors though. The classes Im looking at (ILGenerator, Emit.Label, Emit.DynamicMethod and so on all have "Supported in Windows Phone 8.1" in the Remarks section of their documentation e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.label%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: So you've now converted your whole application to be a Windows Phone Silverlight app?

Comment: I've converted it to a Windows Phone 8.1 app not a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app. Surely a non-universal Windows Phone 8.1 app will not restrict be to the desktop APIs though?

Comment: It's still a Universal app (even though you only target a single platform), and you're trying to use an app from a different platform (i.e. the Silverlight one); This is all in the same way that Linq-to-SQL is supported in Silverlight phone apps, but not Universal ones.

Comment: I wasn't aware that it was still a Universal application if you did not explicitly create one. When creating a new project in Visual Studio you are offered Windows App, Windows Phone App or Universal App. I take it from what you're saying that they are all ultimately Universal apps now, but the Windows app targets the Windows Store and the Windows Phone app targets the Windows Phone store? The app runs great though so I'm baffled as to why we are forced to limit it to the Windows APIs if I have no intention of releasing on that platform.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013, the Windows Phone apps are listed as either "(Windows Phone Silverlight)" or just "(Windows Phone)". The Silverlight ones have the APIs you're after, whilst the non-Silverlight ones won't, as they use the newer APIs more aligned with Universal apps.

Comment: But that's the thing, my current Windows Phone app and the Universal app *do* have these APIs. MSDN says that is has these APIs and the protobuf-net library has been working correctly for weeks on device. It's only when I do the WACK test that these APIs are suddenly unsopprted.